# Cycle2 Initialization events not firing

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-cycle2

I'm using Cycle2 for a basic carousel. My slide items sometimes have a url in their data, so I have to use the Cycle2 api events to use that url when it is there.

My problem is that while the 'cycle-after' event fires fine, none of the initialize events will fire. So if my first slide has a url, nothing happens. This is my code:

```
pressSlideshow.on({
'cycle-post-initialize': function(event) {
    console.log('call');
    var a = $('img.cycle-slide-active');
    var d = a.data('url');
    if (d !== undefined) {
        pressLink.attr('href', a.data('url')).show();
    } else {
        pressLink.hide();
    }
},
'cycle-after': function(event, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
    var a = $(incomingSlideEl);
    var d = a.data('url');
    if (d !== undefined) {
        pressLink.attr('href', a.data('url')).show();
    } else {
        pressLink.hide();
    }
}
});
```

The first event never fires but when I scroll the slideshow the 'cycle-after' event works fine. I've also tried the 'cycle-initialized' event which never fired, and the 'cycle-update-view' event which only fired after scroll but not on initialization.

What gives? & thnx in advance :}

[Cycle2 Events Documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/#events)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just had this same problem.

From the [FAQ](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/faq/)

> ### Why doesn't the cycle-initialized event fire?
>
> It does, I promise. But
>   if you bind your event listener after it has already fired then you
>   won't hear it. Double check that you're not binding too late.

You must bind the event before you run the cycle() init method.

Assuming that your set up your code like:

```
var pressSlideshow = $('.pressSlideshow').cycle();

pressSlideshow.on({
'cycle-post-initialize': function(event) {
    console.log('call');
    var a = $('img.cycle-slide-active');
    var d = a.data('url');
    if (d !== undefined) {
        pressLink.attr('href', a.data('url')).show();
    } else {
        pressLink.hide();
    }
},
'cycle-after': function(event, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
    var a = $(incomingSlideEl);
    var d = a.data('url');
    if (d !== undefined) {
        pressLink.attr('href', a.data('url')).show();
    } else {
        pressLink.hide();
    }
}
});
```

Do this instead:

```
$(document).on('cycle-post-initialize', '.pressSlideshow', function(){
    console.log('call');
    var a = $('img.cycle-slide-active');
    var d = a.data('url');
    if (d !== undefined) {
        pressLink.attr('href', a.data('url')).show();
    } else {
        pressLink.hide();
    }
});

var pressSlideshow = $('.pressSlideshow').cycle();

pressSlideshow.on({
    'cycle-after': function(event, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
        var a = $(incomingSlideEl);
        var d = a.data('url');
        if (d !== undefined) {
            pressLink.attr('href', a.data('url')).show();
        } else {
            pressLink.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Take note of the `.pressSlideshow` selector as yours could differ.

Cheers

Comment: As a caveat to other readers, make sure you are not declaratively initializing the cycle plugin with a class on the parent div like so: class="cycle-slideshow"

Instead, remove that class, and call .cycle() explicitly after you've wired up your event handlers.