# jQuery Cycle2 Event cycle-initialized never firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I 've got an issue with jQueryCycle2,

The event **'cycle-initialized'** never firing

I saw a solution in an old post.
[Cycle2 Initialization events not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734068/cycle2-initialization-events-not-firing)

```
    $(document).on('cycle-initialized', $('#mySlider'), function(){
        // EVENT IS FIRED CORRECTLY
    });
```

But this solution work for only one Slider, I've got 2 slider on my homepage.
Is there anyway to use correctly **cycle-initialized**, **cycle-post-initialize** or **cycle-pre-initialize** in order to initialize severals jqueryCycles

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**So run it on the slideshows instead of `document`**

```
$('#mySlider').on('cycle-initialized', function(){
    // EVENT IS FIRED CORRECTLY
});
```

If they both have a similar class you could cover both with:

```
$('.someClass').on('cycle-initialized', function(){
    // EVENT IS FIRED CORRECTLY
});
```

This code should be placed before the initial `.cycle()` command, if not then `cycle-initialized` will fire before it can be captured; which will make it seem like it never fires.

**EDIT:** Not sure why this is getting downvotes, I have a working example of it [right here](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/9x5wvyr3/)

Comment: put it that way, wont fire the event because the object was already initialized , the correct one is like the @Jaybe wrote, but instead he probably needs to change to a class instead of a id

Comment: @Joyal that's what I put in the comment; that it has to be run before the initial .cycle or it will make it seem like it never fires,

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to add event listener before the cycle is actually initialised 
consider the below answer from FiLeVeR10 
'cycle-initialized' must be called, before calling 'cycle'

```
$('.show').each(function(i) {
    //initialized
    $(this).on('cycle-initialized', function(e, opts) {
        alert('OMG, it hit initialized on '+i+'...');
    })
    //slideshow
    .cycle({
        carouselFluid:      true,
        slides:             'a',
        pauseOnHover:       true
    });
});
```